# Get data from embeded sqlite in package

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I try to read data from database that I made with **Sqlite Browser**. Everything is ok but I can't see results. I copied `mydb.db` to assets folder that I makes in root of project.

Where is my problem?

Thanks.

```
public class DatabasesActivity extends Activity {
  Cursor c;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_databases);

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    try {
      String destPath = "/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases";
      File f=new File(destPath);
      if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();
        f.createNewFile();
        CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
        new FileOutputStream(destPath+"/MyDB"));
      }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.open();

    Cursor c=db.getAllContacts();//.getAllContacts();
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        DisplayContact(c);
      } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
   db.close();
  }

  public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream,
                   OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
    int lenght;
    while ((lenght=inputStream.read(buffer))>0) {
      outputStream.write(buffer,0,lenght);
      Toast.makeText(this,"copy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
  }

  public void DisplayContact(Cursor c) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Name: "+c.getString(1)+"\n"+
                        "Date: "+c.getString(2)+"\n"+
    "Email:                ",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } 
}
```

and this is my **DBAdapter**:

```
public class DBAdapter {

  private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; //used for logging database version changes

  // Field Names:
  public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
  public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
  public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

  public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL};

  // Column Numbers for each Field Name:
  public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
  public static final int COL_TASK = 1;
  public static final int COL_DATE = 2;

  // DataBase info:
  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
  public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contacts";
  public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

  //SQL statement to create database
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT"
                + ");";

  private final Context context;
  private DataBaseHelper DBHelper;
  private SQLiteDatabase db;

  public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
  }

  private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      try {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");
    }
  }

  // Open the database connection.
  public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
  }

  // Close the database connection.
  public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
  }

  // Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
  public long insertContact(String name, String email) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,initialValues);

    // Insert the data into the database.
  }

  // Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
  public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) > 0;
  }

  public Cursor getAllContacts() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
      c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
  }

  /*public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
  }*/

  // Return all data in the database.

  // Get a specific row (by rowId)
  public Cursor getContacts(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
      c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
  }

  // Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
  public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, String email) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    newValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
  }
}
```

Here is my **Sqlite Browser** screenshot:

[image: this is my browser]

Comment: Use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/) instead.

Comment: my compiler doesnt know SQLiteAssetHelper?

Comment: Blue text is a link, and can be clicked.

Comment: my compiler doesnt know SQLiteAssetHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CL. says, you should use [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

If you use gradle based IDE like `Android Studio`, simply add the following dependency in your **app build.gradle** file:

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
```

If you use `Eclipse`, download the latest library JAR and put it in your project's libs folder. Download it from [this JAR link](https://search.maven.org/remote_content?g=com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset&a=sqliteassethelper&v=LATEST).

After you have added the library, extend your **DatabaseHelper** with **SQLiteAssetHelper** by changing the following code of yours in **DatabaseHelper**:

```
private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

to:

```
private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper
```

Then add your database to asset folder, remember to zip or gzip it first, where it reside in database folder like:

```
assets/databases/mydb.db.zip
```

Please read more at [SQLiteAssetHelper github link](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Comment: thank you for your spent time for me...ofcource i will do all your advices.i cant find accept answer button for accept your answer....thank you again

Comment: You can accept answer by clicking a `check` on the top left of the answer. And if you have any question, just create a new question not in your current question here ;).